# Como importar clases en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Cuando se usa `Node.js` para importar una clase seria:

```
var Comprobador = require('./comprobador.js');

let comprobador=new Comprobador();
```

Pero en JavaScript puro en el lado del cliente ¿Cómo seria?

Comment: Casi de la misma forma pero habrá de utilizar compiladores como [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) o transpiladores como [babel](https://babeljs.io/) para la compatibilidad

Comment: @Dev.Joel y de forma nativa no se podria?, si o si usando alguna libreria?

Comment: Dependiendo de qué enfoque, puede cargar el archivo `js` de forma normal o utilizando `JQuery`, pero siguiendo su ejemplo y su sintaxis lo más cercano es los módulos `ES6`.  ¿Desea cargar solo Scripts solamente?

Comment: en realidad no me importa la sintaxis de la importacion, mi objetivo es importar una clase para usarla dentro de otra clase

Comment: No sé si es muy tarde la respuesta pero debes agregar un servidor como _Live Server_, ya que el navegador no te deja leer los ficheros de tu ordenador así nada más.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En versiones anteriores de JavaScript no existía la forma de incluir `JavaScript` ya sea por `import` o `require`.

Las versiones más recientes se añadió la funcionalidad de importar y exportar para satisfacer este punto haciendo uso de los estándares como [Módulos de ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html), solo tenga en cuenta que actualmente, el soporte del navegador para los módulos `ES6` no es muy bueno. Para mejorar esto se usan herramientas de [compilación](https://webpack.github.io/) o [transpilación](https://babeljs.io/) que sería lo más recomendado.

Con estas herramientas será más sencillo y la sintaxis será parecida en algunos casos igual a la que usa en `Node`

Un ejemplo base para crear una clase en un archivo e importarlas en otro. Creamos la clase Persona  con un parámetro en el constructor y un método

```
class Persona {
  constructor(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  saludar() {
     return "Hola mi nombre es " + this.nombre;
  }
}

export default Persona;
```

o simplemente.

```
export default class  Persona {
  constructor(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  saludar() {
     return "Hola mi nombre es " + this.nombre;
  }
}
```

Para llamar en el otro archivo bastará como en su ejemplo

```
import Persona from "./Persona"; // Ruta correcta al archivo Js

let per= new Persona("Stack");
console.log(per.saludar());
```

Comment: lo intente y no funciona, debe ser por lo que dijiste que los navegadores no lo soportan aun

Comment: ojala pueda hacerlo con webpack, aunque browserify tambien ayudaria verdad

Comment: @hubman Sí, también , Mejor añadí un ejemplo base para que quede algo más entendible. Saludos

Comment: Si funciona. Solo que si no utilizas transpiladores debes incluir la ruta con la extensión del archivo, por ejemplo: `import Persona from "./Persona.js";` Y en el código HTML debes llamar tu archivo como `<script src="ruta/archivo.js" type="module"></script>` para que te funcione.

Answer (score 4):

En [ES6](http://es6-features.org/), si tienes una clase llamada:

```
export default class Cliente{
    constructor(nombre, direccion, telefono){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.telefono = telefono
    }

    // Getters, setters, etc
}
```

y esta clase está en `/modulos`, puedes importarla haciendo esto:

```
import Cliente from './modulos/Cliente';
```

También puedes importar funciones, por ejemplo, si tienes un archivo llamado `/modulos/Mates.js`:

```
export var suma = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

export var resta = (a, b) => a - b;

export var multiplicar = (a, b) => a * b;

//etc
```

puedes importar funciones así:

```
import {suma, resta, multiplicar} from './modulos/Mates';
```