# Exportar e importar clases en NODE JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, clase

Estoy intentando crear un **modulo** apartir de una **clase** pero al importarlo se genera un error.

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=16691 applog.js 
>   Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:16691/eb2bbf-a502-435d-9785-efae3b332 For help,see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector Debugger attached.
>
> Waiting for c:\temp\node\logs_old\applog.js:2 import Logs from
>   ("./Modulo/logs.js"); ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 he debugger to disconnect...

Archivo de la clase logs.js

```
class Logs{
  // Modulo exportado
  constructor(path,name,data){
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
    console.log("Objeto log creado OK.");
  }

  getPath() {
    return this.path;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }

  setPath(newPath){
    this.path = newPath;
  }

  setName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
  }

  setData(newData){
    this.data = newData;
  }
}
export default Logs;
```

Archivo applog.js

```
// Importar clases
import Logs from ("./Modulo/logs.js");

// Creacion de objeto
//var applogInstance = new logs();

// Pruebas de metodos
//applogInstance.write('./app.log','app.log','987654');
```

[Como importar clases en JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/como-importar-clases-en-javascript/141092#141092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He realizado la siguiente prueba en donde logro resolver lo que indicas.

He modificado tu archivo logs.js a lo siguiente:

```
class Logs{
  // Modulo exportado
  constructor(path,name,data){
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
    this.data = data;
    console.log("Objeto log creado OK.");
  }

  getPath() {
    return this.path;
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }

  setPath(newPath){
    this.path = newPath;
  }

  setName(newName){
    this.name = newName;
  }

  setData(newData){
    this.data = newData;
  }
}
module.exports = Logs;
```

y lo llamo de la siguiente forma:

```
const Logs = require("./logs.js");
var newInstance = new Logs();
```

generando la salida que tienes definido en el constructor

```
λ node index.js
Objeto log creado OK.
```

Comment: He aplicado los cambios pero se manteniene el resultado:                     Waiting for c:\temp\node\logs_old\applog.js:3
import { Logs } from ("./Modulo/logs.js");
^^^^^^

Comment: He editado la respuesta tras realizar una prueba sobre nodejs para poder validar lo que me indicabas